# I want when user clicks on the part in the displayed model, only that part should be visible

Tags: pythonocc

I want when user clicks on the part on the displayed model, only that part should be visible. but the code is not selecting the part

I tried the below code

```
``from OCC.Display.SimpleGui import init_display
from OCC.Extend.DataExchange import read_step_file
from OCC.Core.AIS import AIS_Shape
display, start_display, _, _ = init_display()
model = read_step_file('C:/Users/Asus/Documents/hello.stp', as_compound=True)
ais_model = AIS_Shape(model)
display.Context.Display(ais_model, True)
def on_select(shape):
    display.Context.RemoveAll()
    ais_selected = AIS_Shape(shape)
    display.Context.Display(ais_selected, True)
    display.FitAll()
display.register_select_callback(on_select)

display.FitAll()
start_display()`
```

`